# F1 as an arguement to shell?

Tags: vb6

Im just trying to understand this code Im working with. I can find sources for single digits @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function
Though I dont see anything there or online

```
Shell ("rundll32.exe """ & App.Path & "\SomeFile.dll"",F1")
'This is from the linked source earlier Shell (pathname, windows style)
```

It may also be using rundll32.exe as for adding the optional F1 arguement
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/164787/info-windows-rundll-and-rundll32-interface

Though I dont see any docs on F1 there either

I could be misreading the quotes. But im pretty sure its passing in the path like so. "rundll32.exe\App.Path\somefile.dll" and the second argument is F1

If someone could either tell me I'm wrong on my quotes and F1 is an argument that would be enough. If it isn't an its a windows style. What it means would be great. Thank you.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking about. Are you asking us about what the rundll32 entry points to SomeFile.dll are? Are you asking what Shell does? Are you asking us why whoever wrote that line was trying to call rundll32 rather than using a Declare statement to execute code in that DLL? Can you clarify what you're asking about?

Comment: I think I understand what its trying to do know. I tried messing around with the command line and those parameters. My issue is understanding the meaning of the F1. Though I think its passing that in as an argument to somefile.dll, based on the error output I get from calling different commands. I think it also actually reads like. 

rundll32.exe "App.path\somefile.dll", F1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, with the quote marks as they are, `F1` is not an argument to `Shell`. It's an argument to `rundll32` and is the entry point into `SomeFile.dll`. This is explained in the link you referenced to `rundll32`.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out with testing random stuff on the shell. Still don't know what its doing. But at least I know its doing something with somefile.dll and not shell. Appreciate it.